# Array element has 0 value even after assigning it

Tags: c, pointers, stack, undefined-behavior, realloc

So I am implementing a stack in c. Now initial stack size is 5 and I double it every time it reaches the limit. I push the values from 1 to 20 in it and then pop it one by one and print it.

Here's the output:  `20, 19, ..., 7, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1` 
Notice the `0` instead of `6`

Here is `stack.c`:

```c
#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 5

struct Stack
{
    int size; // initial size = 5
    int *data; // dynamically allocated array
    int pointer; // position of the top element
};

struct Stack *create_stack()
{
    int *array = calloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY, sizeof(int));
    struct Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));

    if (array == NULL || stack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed in create_stack");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    stack->size = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    stack->data = array;
    stack->pointer = -1;

    return stack;
}

static void resize(struct Stack *stack)
{
    const int new_size = stack->size * 2;

    stack->data = realloc(stack->data, (sizeof *stack->data) * new_size);

    if (stack->data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed in the resize function.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    stack->size = new_size;
}

void push(struct Stack *stack, int element)
{
    int *stack_data = stack->data; // --> I think the bug is here
    stack->pointer = stack->pointer + 1;

    if (stack->pointer >= stack->size)
    {
        printf("Stack is full. Expanding the stack size.");
        resize(stack);
    }

    assert(stack->pointer < stack->size);

    stack_data[stack->pointer] = element;
}
```

But when I change the push function to this everything works and the output is correct:

```c
void push(struct Stack *stack, int element)
{
    stack->pointer = stack->pointer + 1;

    if (stack->pointer >= stack->size)
    {
        printf("Stack is full. Expanding the stack size.");
        resize(stack);
    }

    assert(stack->pointer < stack->size);

    (stack->data)[stack->pointer] = element; // <--- changed line
}
```

How is the output correct now?
What is happening?

Comment: What is the undisclosed `resize`? Does it change `stack->data`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `int pointer;` is a confusing name ... since it's not a pointer. I suggest naming the variables `size` and `capacity`. Note that if one `calloc` or `malloc` fails in `create_stack`, you'll leak the memory of the other.

Comment: @MikeCAT I have added the functions resize and create_stack

Comment: `resize` can change the value of `stack->data`.  If you use the old value saved in `stack_data`, that would be a problem.

Comment: Why do you `malloc` the stack struct at all? The struct is simple enough so one could return it by value. If familiar with C++: You (usually) don't return a `std::vector` or other STL container by pointer either.

Comment: Off-topic: `exit` as error handling usually is not a good idea – you prevent a user of your code from applying her/his own error handling (-> reusability). Similarly the error messages. You should return appropriate values, e.g. an enum with different errors encoded (or maybe even set errno, though I'm not a great friend of) and leave the rest to the caller – she/he might want to print localised error messages, maybe show them in GUI or do something entirely different.

Comment: Aside: Consider using the good `stack->data = realloc(stack->data, (sizeof *stack->data) * new_size);` where size is found with `sizeof *stack->data` in the other allocations: `array = calloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY, sizeof(int));  stack = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));` --> `array = calloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY, sizeof *array); stack = malloc(sizeof *stack);`

Comment: @Aconcagua I am using ```struct Stack``` as incomplete type in the header file. So I can only use it as a pointer. Like encapsulation.

Comment: Never ever do `pointer = realloc(pointer, ...)`! Reallocation might fail, then a null pointer is returned while the old memory remains valid – but you lose the reference to by overwriting the pointer, and if you don't have another you have a memory leak. Better: `tmp = realloc(pointer, ...); if(tmp) { pointer = tmp; } else { /* some appropriate error handling */ }`.

Comment: @Aconcagua: If a program need to acquire the memory it asks for in order to be able to do anything useful, having functions guarantee that they *will not return* if they haven't allocated the required storage will allow downstream code to be simplified.  Allowing functions to return without allocating storage may make it possible to write downstream code that may be able to recover, but add substantial cost to downstream code even in cases where useful recovery would be impossible.

Comment: @supercat And who decides if recovery attempts are meaningful or not? These functions look library like, and I wouldn't want to see the error handling mandated at this level (at this point I miss pretty much the C++ exceptions, which offer to break with least effort and still allow to step in with try-catch at the right point...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: A library author should write functions in whatever way would be most suitable for their customers' needs.  If customers will mostly be targeting platforms that don't guarantee that non-null pointers returned from allocation functions will actually be usable, allowing functions to return without allocating storage will increase client-side complexity for no benefit.

Comment: @supercat And there we are – we won't *ever* be able to know *all* customers' needs. There might be good reasons to still interfere, and possibly `atexit` is not fully suitable for as we might have to handle different failures differently or can go on with parts of the functionality disable (or at least we'd have to introduce a complexity for way worse than a simple if-check after a function call). Being (too?) inflexible for the sake of simple usage for half of your clients risks excluding entirely the other half of your clients as the library renders unusable for them...

Comment: @Aconcagua: If some programs to perform some task would target systems that allow recovery from out-of-memory conditions, and would want to exploit that ability, and others would have no prospect of useful recovery from such conditions, having each kind of program use a library which is designed to meet its need would be better than requiring that all programs include logic to handle OOM conditions whether or not they have any prospect of doing anything other than forcing an abnormal termination.

Comment: @Aconcagua: BTW, if a program's clients will want to be able to recover from out-of-memory conditions, that can be best handled by allowing client code to supply memory-allocation callbacks.  Many embedded operating systems allow programs to use multiple heaps or use other means to guarantee that no matter how much storage some parts of the program try to allocate, they can't cause allocation failures within critical parts of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```c
void push(struct Stack *stack, int element)
{
    int *stack_data = stack->data;
    stack->pointer = stack->pointer + 1;

    if (stack->pointer >= stack->size)
    {
        printf("Stack is full. Expanding the stack size.");
        resize(stack);
        // stack_data still points to old memory allocation
    }

    assert(stack->pointer < stack->size);

    stack_data[stack->pointer] = element;
}
```

Since you modified `stack->data` inside `resize()`, your saved pointer `stack_data` may point to invalid memory locations after `resize()`. You never assigned the new `stack->data` to `stack_data` and you're using the latter directly, which leads to memory access violation.

Your fixed version is using `stack->data` consistently so the above issue doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `stack->data` may be updated by

```
stack->data = realloc(stack->data, (sizeof *stack->data) * new_size);
```

in the `resize` function. However, it is not reflected to the variable `stack_data` and it still points at the old and maybe invalidated place.

To make the function work, you have to assign to `stack_data` after the call of `resize`.

```
void push(struct Stack *stack, int element)
{
    stack->pointer = stack->pointer + 1;

    if (stack->pointer >= stack->size)
    {
        printf("Stack is full. Expanding the stack size.");
        resize(stack);
    }

    int *stack_data = stack->data; // move this after the call of resize()

    assert(stack->pointer < stack->size);

    stack_data[stack->pointer] = element;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean: assign to "stack_data" after the call of resize

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function `realloc` like in this statement

```
stack->data = realloc(stack->data, (sizeof *stack->data) * new_size);
```

it is not necessary that the returned pointer will have the same address as the address stored in the pointer used as function argument.

Thus in the first implementation of the function `push` the pointer `stack_data` after its initialization

```
int *stack_data = stack->data; // --> I think the bug is here
```

is not necessary equal to the value of the pointer `stack->data` after call the function `resize`

```
resize(stack);
```

As a result this statement

```
stack_data[stack->pointer] = element;
```

in general can invoke undefined behavior because there could be used the pointer `stack_data` that points to already freed memory.

In the second implementation of the function `push` there is used the same address of the reallocated memory that was stored in the data member `stack->data`

```
(stack->data)[stack->pointer] = element;
```

So the second function implementation does not have the bug that is present in the first function implementation.

Pay attention to that the functions push and resize should not issue any message. It is the caller of the functions that decides whether to output a message. So the function should have a means to report whether they were successful.

The function can be defined the following way

```
static int resize(struct Stack *stack)
{
    const int new_size = stack->size * 2;

    int *tmp = realloc(stack->data, (sizeof *stack->data) * new_size);

    int success = tmp != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        stack->data = tmp;
        stack->size = new_size;
    }
    
    return success;
}

int push(struct Stack *stack, int element)
{
    stack->pointer = stack->pointer + 1;

    int success = stack->pointer < stack->size;
    
    if ( !success )
    {
        success = resize( stack );
    }

    if ( success ) stack->data[stack->pointer] = element;
    
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your local use of `stack_data`.  Note that [`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) is perfectly allowed to *change* the memory region entirely.  From the man page:

> If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

When you call `resize` (and thus a `realloc`), it's possible the memory area for `stack->data` has changed locations.  If so, when you come back from the `resize` in `push`, `stack_data` no longer points to the valid memory region, and in fact, accessing that `free`d memory invokes undefined behavior.  There's really no point in using a local there, just change `push` to

```
void push(struct Stack *stack, int element)
{
    stack->pointer = stack->pointer + 1;

    if (stack->pointer >= stack->size)
    {
        printf("Stack is full. Expanding the stack size.\n");
        resize(stack);
        // stack->data might point somewhere entirely different now.
    }

    assert(stack->pointer < stack->size);
    // access stack->data directly, no need for a local
    stack->data[stack->pointer] = element;
}
```

I've created an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that potentially illustrates this problem (took a few liberties with parts omitted in the OP). `realloc` doesn't *have* to change the memory region, so you will only see your error *if* that happens: https://godbolt.org/z/4nEoM65Yc